# I'm making a discord bot, and trying to make the code check if there's anything in the requested embed command other than the command

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

Problem is that it sends the message, deletes the command message from the author and **doesn't** send the embed.

Here's my code:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "embed")) { //embed command; /embed
       if (!message.content.includes()) {
           message.delete()
           message.reply("**You can't embed air**")
           return;

           }

           else;
           const embed = new MessageEmbed()
               // Set the title of the field
               .setTitle("Title")
               .setAuthor(message.author.tag)
               // Set the color of the embed
               .setColor(0xff33cc)
               .setFooter("Footer")
               // Set the main content of the embed
               .setDescription(message.content.slice(6, message.content.length));
           // Send the embed to the same channel as the message

           message.channel.send(embed);
       
   }
```

All help is appreciated, and even i think my code looks so dumb it shouldn't work, but googling didn't help and here i am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a tiny bit of indenting error with the if else clause.
Also, the .includes will always return true, as all strings contain the string ""

```
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "embed")) { //embed command; /embed
       if (!message.content.replace(prefix+"embed","").includes()) { //makes sure that the content of the embed is not empty 
           message.delete()
           message.reply("**You can't embed air**")
           return;
       }else{
           const embed = new MessageEmbed()
               // Set the title of the field
               .setTitle("Title")
               .setAuthor(message.author.tag)
               // Set the color of the embed
               .setColor(0xff33cc)
               .setFooter("Footer")
               // Set the main content of the embed
               .setDescription(message.content.slice(6, message.content.length));
           // Send the embed to the same channel as the message
           message.channel.send(embed); 
      }
```

Comment: This code gives the following command: (node:19528) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message

Comment: ah, i'm dumb,  that has nothing to do with your answer, thank you for helping

Comment: @Lauri, all good. just wondering, what did you do wrong?

Comment: The bot was deleting a no longer existing message.